# assert_difference expecting incorrect count, fails as a result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, assertions, minitest

A `Book` has_many `Reviews` and a `Review` belongs_to `Book`. I am using rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0.0p247

I am running the test as follows:

```
test "DELETE destroy should decrement review count by 1" do

    book = Book.create({
                         :isbn=>"1234567890",
                         :title=>"Dummies Guide to Rails",
                         :author=>"KP",
                         :description=>"lorem ipsum"
    })

    # assert_not_nil Book.find_by_isbn('1234567890')

    review = Review.create!({
                              :book_id => book.id,
                              :name => "KP",
                              :email => "KP@KP.com",
                              :description => "Good book.",
                              # :book => book
    })

    assert_difference 'Review.count', 1 , "a review should be deleted" do
      puts Review.count # => 3
      delete :destroy, :book_id => book.id, :id => review.id
      assert_response :redirect
      puts Review.count # => 2
    end
    # puts Review.count
    assert_nil Review.find_by_id(review.id)
  end
```

As you can see, I have printed the count, before and after deleting the review associated with a book, and it decreases by 1. However, the assertions expects and receives incorrect counts, showing this as the error:

```
 1) Failure:
ReviewsControllerTest#test_DELETE_destroy_should_decrement_review_count_by_1 [test/controllers/reviews_controller_test.rb:56]:
a review should be deleted.
"Review.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 4
  Actual: 2
```

I have dropped the db and started with a blank one. I have two questions:

1. I have only created one review associated with one book. Why is the `Review.count` printing 3 and 2 as against 1 and 0?
2. Why does the assertion expect 4, but receive 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 3 records.
If you write `assert_difference 'Review.count', 1`... it expects 4 at the end.
But if you write `assert_difference 'Review.count', -1`... it expects 2, thus 1 less.

Comment: I run the same after `rake db:drop db:migrate db:test:prepare` and get the same counts.

Comment: I don't understand your point with the last comment. But if you as second parameter in `assert_difference` has an positive value it expects `Review.count` to be incresed. If you have an negative value it expects it to decrese.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean to say, that the before and after counts should be 1 and 0, since I am only creating one book and review for the purpose of the test. Then how come I am getting count as 4 and 2?

Comment: I think I am too confused. The test has passed for now, but I need to investigate the numbers. EDIT: Turns out there were fixtures that were messing up the counts. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This line tells that you are expecting the difference of Plus one(1 or +1).

```
assert_difference 'Review.count', 1 , "a review should be deleted"
```

But actually you want the difference in Negative one(-1), so you should write

```
assert_difference 'Review.count', -1 , "a review should be deleted"
```

For more guide visit [assert_difference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html)